# How to enable Online/offline mode for firebase firestore?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

Is there a way to create online and offline mode for users with `firestore`?

I found a tutorial is this still up to date or is there a easier way?

Tutorial: https://blog.campvanilla.com/firebase-firestore-guide-how-to-user-presence-online-offline-basics-66dc27f67802

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Firestore SDK doesn't have a way to tell if the user is online (connect) or offline.  However, you can do this with Realtime Database, which is what the tutorial you linked to is helping you work through.  It's suggesting that you can use Realtime Database in tandem with Firestore to support online presence.  You will definitely need the Realtime Database component to make this work.

Comment: I haven't read it thoroughly, but it seems to be on the right track.

Comment: Can someone help me with this example I am in trouble